# fix for electron modules remote & dialog.showOpenDialog

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron, modal-dialog, renderer

this is my code

```
const parse = require('csv-parse');
var $ = global.jQuery = require('jquery');
const electron = require('electron');
const { dialog } = require('electron');  
const fs = require('fs');      
const path = require("path");

function myImage() {
    dialog.showOpenDialog({properties: ['openFile']}).then(result => {
        if (result.canceled) {
            console.log("No file selected!")
        } else {
            const filePath = result.filePaths[0];
            const fileName = path.basename(filePath);
            imgFolderPath = path.join(app.getPath('userData'), fileName);
            fs.copyFile(filePath, imgFolderPath, (err) => {
                if (err) throw err;
                console.log(fileName + ' uploaded.');
            });
        }
    });

}

$("#uploadMyImg").on("click", () => {
    myImage()
});
```

this is the console when I click **uploadMyImg Button**

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'showOpenDialog' of undefined
```

has electron changed something or am I doing something wrong

and this is the code from main.js (electron)

should I use some other module

```
const {app , BrowserWindow , ipcMain} = require('electron')

let mainWindow 
function createMainWindow() {
    mainWindow = new BrowserWindow ({
        autoHideMenuBar: true,
        resizable: false,
        width: 1920,
        height: 1080,
        webPreferences: {
            nodeIntegration: true,
            contextIsolation: false,
            enableRemoteModule: true
        }
    })

    mainWindow.loadFile('./newClient.html')

}

app.on('ready',() => {
    createMainWindow()

    mainWindow.on('ready',() => mainWindow = null)

})

app.on('window-all-closed', function () {
    if (process.platform !== 'darwin') app.quit()
})
```

has electron changed something ???

Comment: Can you add your electron code?

Comment: yes just added it , so is everything fine in renderer side?

Answer (score 1):

You can't import `dialog` directly from electron you should use via `remote` like this;

```
const { remote } = require('electron');
let dialog = remote.dialog
```